# Why empty dictionary getting returned from a java script function

Tags: javascript

In this below code snippet, the last console log is displaying(the node value) empty dictionary, could you let me know the reason?

```
node = {};
list1=[1,2,3];
for(each in list1){
    console.log(node);
    var abc = function(t1, key){
        t1[key] = {};
        return t1;
    }
    node=abc(node, list1[each])[list1[each]]
}
console.log(node)
```

Comment: What is expected output? I can't really see what are you trying to accomplish...

Comment: I am expecting {1:{2:3}}. If list1 is [1,2,3,4] then I will expect {1:{2:{3:4}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting node variable in every loop iteration. Try to make a backup reference:

```js
node = {};
nodebackup = node;
list1=[1,2,3];
for(each in list1){
    console.log(nodebackup);
    var abc = function(t1, key){
        t1[key] = {};
        return t1;
    }
    node=abc(node, list1[each])[list1[each]]
}
console.log(nodebackup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you create with `list1[each]` which is basically 1 ... 3 an new property, which is an object. This object is assigned to node.

```js
var abc = function(t1, key) {
    t1[key] = {};
    return t1;
}

var node = {},
    list1 = [1, 2, 3],
    each;

for (each in list1) {
    console.log(node);
    console.log(abc(node, list1[each])[list1[each]]);
    console.log(list1[each]);
    node = abc(node, list1[each])[list1[each]];
}

console.log(node);
```

To get an object with the wanted properties, you could use another variable and move the new objects inside of the given object.

```js
var abc = function(t1, key) {
    t1[key] = {};
    console.log(t1);
    return t1[key]; // return new object
}

var node = {},
    temp = node,
    list1 = [1, 2, 3],
    each;

for (each in list1) {
    temp = abc(temp, list1[each]); // assign just the new object
}

console.log(node);
```

Comment: Could you let me know what t1 will have before returning?